# Comparison of data from COM port

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I'm new to Python and I need help , this MAC Adress comparison does not work

> > > > if (joined_seq) == "38aa3c06f813":

from com port I get mac addresses but I can not compare them

dc7144xxxxxx

e49e12xxxxxx

e49e12xxxxxx

f4cae5xxxxxx

e0cec3xxxxxx

If you can suggest the correct method I will be very grateful
Thanks!!

```html
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',\
    baudrate=115200,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

#this will store the line
seq = []

while True:
    for c in ser.read():
        seq.append(chr(c)) #convert from ANSII
        joined_seq = ''.join(str(v) for v in seq) #Make a string from array
        #f = open("data2.txt", "w")
        #f.write(joined_seq)      # str() converts to string
        #f.close()
          
        if chr(c) == '\n':
            #print(joined_seq)
            if (joined_seq) == "38aa3c06f813":
                print("bingo")
            
            break


ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

now works it was necessary to add

> > ( \n )  at the end of the mac address

```html
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',\
    baudrate=115200,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

#this will store the line
seq = []


mac = "38aa3cxxxxxx\n"

while True:
    for c in ser.read():
        seq.append(chr(c)) #convert from ANSII
        joined_seq = ''.join(str(v) for v in seq) #Make a string from array
        #f = open("data2.txt", "w")
        #f.write(joined_seq)      # str() converts to string
        #f.close()
          
        if chr(c) == '\n':
            #print(joined_seq)
            seq = []
            if (joined_seq) == mac:
                print("BingoBongo")
            
            break


ser.close()
```